# Vertex AI cost and usage tracking

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Is there a way to track and monitor the usage of Vertex AI by roles/projects? We wanted to calculate the cost per user group and charge back that amount to the respective groups.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check using [Billing Reports](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/reports#filtering_and_grouping) to track and monitor usage and cost incurred of Vertex AI **per project** with the following filters:

[image]